# Reducing the number of bits in UUID

Tags: java, math, numbers, bit

I have a use-case for getting distributed unique sequence numbers in integer format. UUID comes out to be the best and simple solution for me.

However, I need to have integers only, so I will convert that big hexadecimal number (UUID) to decimal number. UUID has 128 bits and hence will produce a decimal number of 39 digits.

I can't afford to have 39 digits number due to some strict database constraints. So, I get back to basics and try to convert the number to binary first and then decimal. Now, the standard process of converting a hexadecimal directly to binary is to take each hexadecimal digit and convert it into 4 bits. Each hexadecimal number can be converted to a set of 4  bits. Hence, for 32 hex digits in UUID, we get 128 bits (32*4) .

Now, I am thinking of not to follow the rule of converting each hexadecimal digit to 4 bits. Instead I will just use enough bits to represent that digit.

For example , take 12B as one hexadecimal number.
By standard process, conversion to binary comes out to be 0000-0001-0010-1011 (9 bits actually).
By my custom process, it comes out to be 1-10-1011 (7 bits actually).

So, by this method, number of bits got reduced. Now if bits reduced, the digits in the converted decimal number will get reduced and can live with my constraints.

Can you please help in validating my theory? Does this approach has some problem? Will this cause collision ? Is the method correct and can I go ahead with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A UUID is 128 bits long. Any storage that uses less than 128 bits will risk collisions. Does your database not support a UUID type? Most do.

Comment: Per the Pigeonhole Principle, any scheme you come up with to map x unique values to y unique values, where y < x, will potentially result in collisions.

Comment: What about using plain `Math.random()` or `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will cause collisions.

e.g.

```
0000-0001-0010-1011 -> 1101011
0000-0000-0110-1011 -> 1101011
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I spend couple of days debugging problems with UUID collisions (UUIDS were trimmed), debuging these things is a nightmare. You won't have a good time.

What you need is just to implement your own unique identifier shema --- depending on your use case developing such schema could be either very easy or very hard. You could for example assign each machine an unique number (lets say two bytes) and each machine would assing IDS serialy from 4 byte namespace. And in 6 bytes you have a nice UUID-like schema (with some constraints).